# Gerar botão em DIV?

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma DIV chamada ( `meusBotoes` ) e eu gostaria que a cada `loop` do `while` gera um botão dentro da `DIV` com o valor da variável `$nome` e com o `onclick` que chama a função exibirAlerta().

Meu `while`

```
<?php
$host = "";
$bd = "";
$usr = "";
$psw = "";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $usr, $psw, $bd);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
die("A conexão falhou, consulte o suporte: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, imagem FROM produtos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$id = $row['id'];
$nome = $row['nome'];
$tipo = $row['tipo'];
$imagem = $row['imagem']; 
}

}
?>
```

Existe um jeito fácil de fazer isso em `PHP` mesmo, sem `Javascript`?

Comment: O que você já tentou? Fala em escrever dentro de um DIV, mas não o mostra no código onde ele está. Se o seu PHP retorna um HTML, é só uma questão de fazer um echo '<input type="button" ...' a cada iteração, ou incrementar uma variável com esses inputs pra dar um echo dentro DIV mais tarde no código...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente é isso, jogar o `while` dentro da `div`:

connect_query.php

```
<?php
$host = "";
$bd = "";
$usr = "";
$psw = "";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $usr, $psw, $bd);
if($conn->connect_error) 
{    die("A conexão falhou, consulte o suporte: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT id, nome, tipo, imagem FROM produtos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);  
?>
```

pag_btn.php

```
<?php include 'connect_query.php';?>
<div id="meusBotoes ">
    <?php     
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {    $id = $row['id'];
         $nome = $row['nome'];
         $tipo = $row['tipo'];
         $imagem = $row['imagem']; 
         echo"<button id=".$nome." onclick='exibirAlerta()'>".$nome."</button>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Show de bola. Isso mesmo que eu queria. Muito Obrigado.